# How much battery does GPS consume?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, android-googleapiclient, google-location-services

According to the [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), GPS is most accurate but quickly consumes battery power. The document recommends that battery power should be among the things to take into account but from that document there is no example of a bad usage.
Could someone please provide such an example.
I am asking because I am thinking of a usecase such as 
E.g. if capturing the user location 16 times in a day (in 30 mins intervals). Would that be a bad use case model?

Comment: Question is off topic for SO. Anyway, smartphones of medium level produced by major brands in the latest 3-4 years are able to track running sessions lasting 2 hours with points distant 5/10 meters and they drain no more than 10% of the battery if the monitor is off. Therefore your use case seems to be nearly at 0 impact

Comment: @perissf:I updated the OP. Is that an improvement being a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Here is a very basic example of setting up a timeout feature for location requests.

```
public class MyLocationManager implements LocationListener {

    private static final int LOCATION_UPDATE = 1;

    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public MyLocationManager(Context context) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case LOCATION_UPDATE:
                        stopLocationUpdates();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        mHandler.removeMessages(LOCATION_UPDATE);
    }

    public void requestLocationUpdates(long timeOut) {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(LOCATION_UPDATE, timeOut);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

---

To answer the title of your post: It varies based on the device.

To get into more detail, it really depends on how you set up your requests. In your case, you say you want 16 points in 30 minute intervals, which won't put much impact on power if you receive them all within a second of the request. However, you never specified how long you would wait for the location to arrive or what the accuracy of location point you were requesting should be. So in theory, you could keep the GPS module running indefinitely if you are looking for 10m accuracy points in a basement.

**My recommendation**

Find out the max accuracy of a location point you need before it is completely unusable, and have a solid timeout feature in place. GPS by itself doesn't kill the battery, it's the combination of the device being awake to receive the location and the GPS module being on that kills battery life. Keeping the device on for ~2 min total to receive 16 points (~8 second timeout) should have negligible impact on battery.

Comment: I am interested in an accuracy of within 3m (no basements or anything like that are of concern). What do you mean by the timeout? I see a min interval in the LocationManager API for the what would be the every 30mins I am interested in but not a timeout. Could you please give or point out some example of the approach you are describing?

Comment: That accuracy is possible, but I would only expect that in the best situation (outside, no buildings). In regards to the timeout, if you call `requestLocationUpdates()`, unless you explicitly call `removeUpdates()`, LocationManager will continuously poll for location until it receives one, which could be indefinite if you are in a GPS deprived area. Even if you set minTime to 30 min, unless you get a point right away, the GPS module will stay on until you receive a point.

Comment: Is there any online good example that I can use for reference for this approach?

Comment: Added an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. So it is just a delayed cancellation. But the fact that I reached the timeout what does it mean? That the user is somewhere that makes it very time consuming to get the location (e.g. subway)? And if I end up in timeout is there a strategy e.g. retry after X mins or most likely I will get timeout again? Or should I be rescheduling and timing out until I get the position? Or if a timeout occurs it means that it is better not to retry?